# Script to check server for WordPress installs and report version information

Tags: security, scripting, wordpress

I'm looking for a script that can be run on a linux server that will find all WordPress installs and report their versions, or report if a version is out of date. I've googled for something and it looks like Fantastico and Scriptalicious do this, but only if you install WordPress using their system.

I'm not against writing my own script, and will do so should there be nothing out there but I thought I'd ask first before putting in the time myself.

EDIT: I found http://code.google.com/p/wordpress-butler/ after a few more hours of searching. I'll be giving it a try, but it hasn't been updated since 2009.

Comment: What have you tried, why didn't it do what you want? You may be better off asking over on wordpress.stackexchange.com.

Comment: I haven't tried anything as I haven't found anything that fits this description. I thought I'd check here first as it is a server administration script I'm looking for, thought was a better fit here but will try wp.stack should no answers turn up.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
find . -name 'version.php' -path '*wp-includes/*' -print -exec grep '$wp_version =' {} \; -exec echo '' \;
```

Answer (score 3):

A while back I wrote [CrudMiner](https://github.com/mricon/CrudMiner) for this particular purpose -- checking what sorts of crap is installed in the webroot of a large client-managed vhost server. It's both simple and powerful, but I have changed jobs since then and haven't been able to maintain the version info for the products.

If you are willing to help out with keeping an eye on wordpress versions, it'll do what you need. :)

Comment: very cool, I'll check this out and see how it fairs with wp-butler